# Text input limiting to less than 31 (days)

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use text input to ask for day in a form, but I don't know how to use this pattern attribute well. Maybe I should use some those regex with less than 31? I don't really know how to make one either.

This is how it looks:

```
<input type='text' name='d' size='2' maxlength='2' value='$d'     pattern='[0-3]{1}[1-9]{1}'  required>
```

I know it would be easier to just use select or number, but i have to do this as text.

Comment: RegEx can be used to deny many obviously incorrect inputs, but it cannot correctly validate a date. This is particularly complicated due to leap year rules.

Comment: And if i would like only to limit it to be less than 31, how should i do it using RegEx? i mean how to make a proper RegEx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! It is very possible.
The regex that you need is `^([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$`

Basically, it will accept any text that is:

1. A **single** digit 1 to 9,
2. **Two digits** where the first is 1 or 2 and the second is 0 to 9, *or*
3. **Two digits** where the first is 3 and the second is 0 or 1

If you have access to JavaScript & you know the month, you could dynamically change the pattern to

- `^([1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)$` for months with 30 days, or
- `^([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])$` for February *on a non-leap year*, or
- `^([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])$` for February *on a leap year*.

Good luck! I've never seen that `pattern` attribute before... good to know!

Read more: [Matching Numeric Ranges with a Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html)

Comment: Are you asking for reputation points? I have already I submitted answer and also accepted by @Focus74  This is totally wrong to ask for points and even someone already provide solution which solved your problem.

Comment: @RahulDambare It's perfectly normal for other answers to be accepted instead after the initial accepted answer. "Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you; it is earned by convincing your peers that you know what you’re talking about." (StackOverflow Help Page). If you look at my answer, I think you will see that I earned those points, and my comment never tried to circumvent the natural reasons for upvoting.

Comment: Both of your answers were helpful :) Thank you both very much!

Comment: Yes, I would recommend using a combination of both of our answers. Because my answer doesn't have the benefit of an "autocorrect" like his does.

Comment: All things were good @4castle . now I want to implement this regex for 12 months how could I?

Comment: @UmaShankar yes of course! That regex would be `^([1-9]|1[012])$` See the link in my answer for an explanation of how it works.

Comment: tq nd rate 5/5 for Link

Answer (score 1):

use input type number

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="31" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript function `onchange` event -

```
<script>
  function handleChange(input) {
    if (input.value < 1) input.value = 1;
    if (input.value > 31) input.value = 31;
  }
</script>
```

So call javascript function in input box onchange event.

```
<input type="text" onchange="handleChange(this);" />
```